How to close a MAUI App (Android) without exiting?
I am trying to figure out how to close an MAUI app but without Quiting the application so it goes to the background.

The user does this.  Why would your app need to do this on its own?

You can use MoveTaskToBack(true) to go to the background.

@Jason. I have got a Modal Login Page with sits on top  1st page. When taps the back-button on that modal login page, it goes to the first app page. Which is not something I want. What I want is: that the app disappears but without 'Quit()'ing the app. Makes sense?

You need to fix your navigation.  What you’re attempting is bad UX and likely a violation of App Store rules

@Jason. What should I consider instead? And which aspect in particular is against store rules? Is it the disappearance of the app when user back-clicks from a Login page?

Normally, the user closes the app, just as Jason said.
